# Python module import in interactive shell

Tags: python, shell, import, module, interactive

I moved my python module into the site-package folder along with the working default modules, but when I choose to import my modules they come back with this error.

```
    >>> import go

    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
           import go
    ImportError: No module named go
```

Comment: ALWAYS use virtualenv. `virtualenv env` then `activate env/bin/activate` then do your pip install.. it should work after

Answer (score 2):

`site-packages` folder is for Python packages. Please do not try to just copy files there.

[For how to create and install Python package please read Python packaging tutorial](http://packaging.python.org/).

Comment: I appreciate the tip. I recently created a virtual environment and imported my modules in there, but i'm still having the issue of trying to import my modules in the interactive shell